# Filtered & ordered form datasheet to local table

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I've been struggling all afternoon to write a function that will cache the displayed records in a form datasheet to a temporary table.

The use-case is that the user uses the datasheet auto-filters & sorting to get the records into their desired form. Then they're running a report function that outputs what they see as xml, runs it through an xslt transform to html. I can't get MSXML working direct from queries, hence the need for a local cached copy of what the user sees in the form datasheet.

What I have so far works, but seemingly ignores the filter & order by clauses in the sql string.

```vb
Private Sub CacheLocalTemp()

      Dim strSql As String: strSql = "SELECT * INTO rpt_TEMP FROM tbl_Outputs"

      If Len(Me.Filter) > 0 Then
          strSql = strSql & " WHERE " & Me.Filter
      End If

      If Len(Me.OrderBy) > 0 Then
          strSql = strSql & " ORDER BY " & Me.OrderBy
      End If

      DoCmd.SetWarnings False
          DoCmd.RunSQL strSql
      DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub
```

I've seen methods using INSERT and SELECT INTO VALUES (x, y z), but didn't want to go down this route as it would mean I need to hard-code all field names, and there are a lot over about 10 different forms.

All the code I'm finding is long-winded / excessive, and I am astounded there isn't a more elegant / straight-forward way of just dumping a snapshot copy of what is displayed in the datasheet straight into its own table.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can remove the ORDER BY part, as it won't do anything. ORDER BY is about output, not input. Here, you're putting records into a table, not reading them out. Not scolding, just helping you simplify your problems. Still thinking about the rest of it... just thought I'd add the side note.

Comment: have you stepped through the code or used a watch to make sure the value of strSql is what you think it is when it hits DoCmd?

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't really precious about ORDER BY as I can do the ordering in the XSLT script to render the XML.

Comment: I had stepped through the code and the strSql was fine at the point of execution. I even ran strSql as a normal SELECT query in the GUI (removing the "INTO rpt_TEMP" part), and it returned the desired results. 

I'd still be interested to find out why the WHERE clause didn't work as part of the INTO query. Perhaps that's a limitation of SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem pretty easily by using a helper function that outputs a recordset to a table.

Helper function:

```vb
Public Sub RecordSetToTable(rs As DAO.Recordset, tableName As String)
    Dim td As DAO.TableDef
    Set td = CurrentDb.CreateTableDef(tableName)
    Dim fld As DAO.Field
    For Each fld In rs.Fields
        td.Fields.Append td.CreateField(fld.Name, fld.Type, fld.Size)
    Next
    CurrentDb.TableDefs.Append td
    Dim tableRS As DAO.Recordset
    Set tableRS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(tableName)
    rs.MoveFirst
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        tableRS.AddNew
        For Each fld In rs.Fields
            tableRS.Fields(fld.Name).Value = fld.Value
        Next
        tableRS.Update
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
End Sub
```

On the form:

```vb
Private Sub CacheLocalTemp()
     RecordSetToTable Me.Recordset, "rpt_TEMP"
End Sub
```

No messing around with constructing queries, ordering, etc. Just write the recordset straight to a new table.

Comment: Just incorporated this in my application, and it solved my problem. I added in a line immediately before CurrentDb.TableDefs.Append td to delete the temp table if it already exists.